# Is it possible to re-Initialize beans in Spring at runtime?

Tags: spring, jms

We have a Spring web application that is online pretty much 24x7. This application uses JMS to send and receive messages from other systems. For the most part everything works as expected. However, occasionally we have issues where either our network fails or the backend JMS provider (JBOSS 5.1.0.GA) hangs and has to be restarted. So for various reasons the web-application looses it's connection to the JMS provider. The only way we've been able to reestablish a connection is by re-starting the servlet container (tomcat).

Is there a way to re-init the ConnectionFactory bean at runtime ? We've defined the following bean in our applicationContext.xml :

```
      <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
        <property name="cache" value="false" />
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" />
            <property name="jndiTemplate">
                    <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
            </property>
            <property name="jndiName">
                    <value>ConnectionFactory</value>
            </property>
    </bean>
```

Is there a way to re-init the bean so that the bean re-establishes a connection to the provider ? We would like to do this while the application is live and avoid re-starting the app or the servlet.

Is this even possible in spring ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to wrap this connectionFactory around a Spring provided ConnectionFactory - [CachingConnectionFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html) which has support for automatic recovery of connections.

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="5"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the ConnectionFactory is already wrapped around Spring's CachingConnectionFactory. Yet the connections are not recovering on errors. We did that to avoid creating and tearing down connections with every message being sent / received. Is there something else that can be done ?